# How to solve "Notice: Undefined index: ..."

Tags: php, notice

how can i hide the php notice by solving the issue.

my code

```
if(empty($_GET['mode']) && !$_GET['page']) { 
    include($basepath.'/templates/template.home.php');
}
```

**Notice: Undefined index: page in /var/www/public_html/index.php on line 1**

i tried like this

```
if(empty($_GET['mode']) && !isset($_GET['page']) && !$_GET['page']) { 
    include($basepath.'/templates/template.home.php');
}
```

but still showing the

**Notice: Undefined index: page in /var/www/public_html/index.php on line 1**

how can i solve/fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you use in both statements `!$_GET['page']` when using `&&` operator.

When you use `!$_GET['page']` in both cases even if you added `!isset($_GET['page']` this condition is checked in `$_GET['mode']` is empty.

You simple should probably change your statement from:

```
if(empty($_GET['mode']) && !$_GET['page']) { 
    include($basepath.'/templates/template.home.php');
}
```

into

```
if(empty($_GET['mode']) && !isset($_GET['page'])) { 
    include($basepath.'/templates/template.home.php');
}
```

In this case simple if `$_GET['page']` is not set (and of course mode is empty) you should include homepage template

Comment: Very nice explanation, but that last mention of `$_GET['page']` is missing an apostrophe. :)

Comment: @ljacqu Thanks. I've just fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Either `mode` or `page` isn't present in the array `$_GET` - so you need to test for it using [`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)